# 'str' object has no attribute 'append' when trying to append to a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, file, append

When I try to use the .append operator in python to append to a read json file it returns an error 'str' object has no attribute 'append. I've tried multiple different ways to go about it and I can't seem to find a work around.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AMr9.png)

```
import json
def addContact():
    file = open("db.json", "r")
    information = file.read()
    firstName = str(input("Please enter the desired first name:\n"))
    lastName = str(input("Please enter the desired last name:\n"))
    phoneNumber = str(input("Please enter the desired phone number:\n"))
    jsonAddData = {
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber
    }
    information.append(jsonAddData)
    return

def listRecords():
    
    return

def findFirst():
    
    return

def delFirst():
    
    return


def commandFunction():
    go = True
    while go == True:
        print("Please select an option from the menu:\n1.Add Contact.\n2.List all records.\n3.Find first value from search.\n4.Delete first value from search.\n5.Quit.")
        try:
            userInput = int(input("\n"))
        except:
            print("please enter a proper value")
        if(userInput == 1):
            addContact ()
        elif(userInput == 2):
            listRecords()
        elif(userInput == 3):
            findFirst()
        elif(userInput == 4):
            delFirst()
        elif(userInput == 5):
            break
        
        break
commandFunction()
```

Comment: `information = file.read()` returns a string, which you need to convert to an object (presumably a list) using `json.loads` (or alternatively, just read the file directly using `json.load`) to be able to append to it.

Comment: `information` is a string, and as the error says, you can't append to a string. You want to instead use the `json` module to parse `information`  to Python objects, then you can append to the JSON array,

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for the tip I have fixed my code using the information you have given me.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the tip I have fixed my code using the information you have given me.